# Gradle Error with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to Android and due to some reason, I am getting following o/p in grade console. Not able to resolve. Can anyone give a suggestion to resolve this error?

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
WARNING: Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (25.0.1) and test app (25.0.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2501Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (25.0.1) and test app (25.0.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
 FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. See console for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 8.644 secs
```

build.gradle(Project) contain the following data

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(app) contains the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.team.test"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: avoid using `25.+`. In your case, your test dependencies apparently need `25.0.0` so use that instead

Comment: I tried the same and still I am getting the same error, which is following :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
Conflict with dependency 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core'. Resolved versions for app (1.3) and test app (1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. 
* Try
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED

Comment: `compile 'junit:junit:4.12'` should be `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Resolved, I was behind this issue for 2 days.

Comment: What helped you resolve the issue?

Comment: When I had changed from compile 'junit:junit:4.12' to testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12', it worked.